# Execute a same action multiple times in parallel and looping on it

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm trying introduce myself to parallel programming but I'm not sure I'm thinking the right way. I have multiple instances of a same class which I want to execute a same task simultaneously. After this, the threads wait for x time and perform the action again.

I currently thought about something like this

```
public class RunnableT implements Runnable {

 @Override
 public void run() {

     while(!Main.stop) {
         //Perform task
         //Wait to mask next action
     }

 }
}
```

And so I would have a main thread like that:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static boolean stop;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        stop = false;
        
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new RunnableT());
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new RunnableT());
        t2.start();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //Call t1 & t2 to perform the action
            //Wait a second
            //Loop
        }
    
        stop = true;
    }

}
```

I know I'm doing it wrong but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `Call t1 & t2 to perform the action`. Usually interaction between threads is done using (synchronized) queues, the best candidate is `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Create `ArrayBlockingQueue` in the main class, let the main thread put tasks in it, and let worker threads read from it and perform tasks.

UPDT. If you want each task be executed by each thread, then create 2 queues, one for each thread, and let each thread read only its own thread, while main thread creates next task and put it in both threads.